# Add option to "Extend to the Left" in XFCE4 Display Settings

Tags: xfce4

I have a shortcut to "xfce4-display-settings -m" that displays the following options when I have two monitors connected:

- Laptop
- Mirror Displays
- Extend to the Right
- Monitor

I would like to also see "Extend to the Left." What can I do to make that option appear?

---

**Note**: I am running Ubuntu 12.10 with xubuntu-desktop installed.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to add an option to the GUI way. I can provide a script which you can run or bind a keyboard shortcut to, if you want.

Comment: A script that applied that option would satisfy my use-case, so yes, I'd appreciate it if you wrote one and posted it as an answer.

Comment: The GUI is the same in Ubuntu 14.04, still no way to change that GUI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command is simple:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --left-of eDP1
```

You will have to find the names of the displays and edit the command accordingly. To do so, simply run `xrandr` without arguments.

Comment: But how to change the menu entry itself to "Extend to the Left"?

Comment: the problem is that the extended display becomes in fact the primary

Comment: Very thorough [answer here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290346/xfce4-display-settings-why-is-there-no-extend-to-the-left/290350?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). The short version is: not possible, because as @cipricus points out, XFCE apparently treats the left as the primary. Work-a-rounds with `xrand`  as posted by @mreq (or other manual config) seems to be the only option currently